# Como fazer autenticação ao consumir um serviço SOAP?

Tags: c#, web-service

Preciso fazer chamadas a um Web Service para enviar algumas informações.

Fiz do seguinte modo:

- Iniciei uma aplicação WinForm
- Importei o endereço que virou o .WSDL no projeto
- Importei as classes e as utilizei corretamente colocando os valores para suas propriedades

Abaixo demonstro simplificadamente as classes e como eu fiz:

```
PortTypeClient Servico = new PortTypeClient();
DownpaymentRequest Numerario = new DownpaymentRequest();
header Header = new header();

itemData[] Array_Item = new itemData[1];

itemData Item = new itemData();

DownPaymentResponse Response = new DownPaymentResponse();

Header.tx_company_code = "1021";
Header.tx_document_type = "KA";     
Item.tx_account = "10184958";
Item.tx_gl_indicator = "A";     
Array_Item[0] = Item;
Numerario.header = Header;
Numerario.item = Array_Item;

try
{
  // onde de fato envio a requisição e pego a resposta no Response :)
  Response = Servico.PostInboundDownpayment(Numerario);
}
catch  (Exception error)
{
  MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
}
```

Não há nenhuma classe que contenha alguma propriedade para informar login/senha.

Eu sei (está mais para **eu acho**) que desta forma funciona **sem login/senha**.

Minha pergunta é:

Sendo um Web Service e enviando do modo que demonstro, onde eu passaria o login/senha se as classes não têm uma propriedade para tal informação?

Teria outro modo de envio que eu desconheço?

**EDITADO ABAIXO**...
Bom dia..Solicitei uma área de teste para conectar e enviar as informações.
Os donos do SERVIDOR retiraram a necessidade de login e senha
Agora, no C# estou tendo outro problema..
Consigo enviar pelo SOAP UI informando a ACTION conforme imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como devo proceder para passar essas informações no código acima?

Comment: Depende de como funciona a autenticação do WebService.

Comment: Btw, uma dica: a leitura da sua publicação seria muito mais fluída se tivesse menos ruído nela, tanto no título quanto na publicação em si. Quanto ao título, você pode dar apenas uma breve descrição para o problema, não precisa informar tecnologia, pois o sistema de tags serve justamente para este propósito. Note que isto é uma dica minha pra você, não tem nenhuma relação com regras do site ou algo parecido.

Comment: A authenticação e authorização depende de como funciona o WebService... veja se a sua instância do `PortTypeClient` não possui a propriedade `ClientCredentials`, `Credentials` ou `AuthUser`

Comment: Boa tarde LINQ.. Vou verificar como funciona a autenticação do webservice... Você saberia dizer quais os tipos que existe? Uma breve explanação para me dar um NORTE e eu saber o que procurar? :) e Obrigado pela dica do "mais fluida". Eu acho que com o tempo e pratica consigo fazer como tu descreve :)

Comment: Boa tarde Leandro Angelo... como falei com o LINQ irei verificar que tipo de autenticação é. Na realidade até então eu achava que era por uma propriedade do objeto.. tipo como tu descreveu .. PortTypeClient.Clientexxx ou outra propriedade qualquer.. Mas se tem eu não achei.. e olhei esmiuçadamente o wsdl e nada..Nada que indicasse o uso de login/ senha em alguma propriedade.. Obrigado pela atenção :) Como perguntei para o LINQ.. você saberia dizer os tipos de autenticação que existem para que eu possa pesquisar mais certeiramente?? :)

Comment: Ok... apresente o wsdl do serviço. Pergunta boba, você não está conseguindo fazer a requisição por que ele está pedindo as credenciais?

Comment: Boa tarde @LeandroAngelo . Ao enviar o exemplo acima me retorna a sequinte mensagem.: ERROR : Unauthorized(401) - Creio que seja dizendo que não tem autorização .. correto??

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o endereço do wsdl é : https://esbdev.abbott.com:443/eProxy/service/Symphony_AccountingService_Router?wsdl

Comment: @RicardoM.Souza Existem diversos tipos, nem teria como listar. Sobre a escrita: com certeza você vai melhorando sim. Btw, outra dica, quando você for citar alguém no comentário pode usar o @ isso vai fazer com que a pessoa seja notificada =D

Comment: Pelo wsdl não parece haver alguma authenticação no envelope do serviço, então a restrição deve ser por basic authentication, restriçao por IP ou alguma chave que você deve passar no header da requisição... Perceba que no serviço existe também um objeto header com alguns parâmetros que você está passando vazio. E por fim, até agora você não apresentou qual é o erro que o seu código está retornando.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo O erro eu coloquei na resposta acima.. :) O que seria por BASIC auhentication? Como eu passaria algo por essa BASIC AUTHENTICATION, tendo em vista o código que desenvolvi?

Comment: Bom dia @LeandroAngelo .. Editei a pergunta.. Você teria algum conhecimento sobre isso?